# use jquery to select a dropdown option on button click

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I want to use jQuery to select an option, say the 3th item, in a DropDownList by clicking  a button, then have the DropDownList box change it's value, say '44'.

```
           <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">SELECT</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">23</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">32</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">44</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">61</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 $("#<%=DropDownList2.ClientID%>").val('3');
```

Answer (score 0):

First set `ClientIDMode` to `Static` as ID may be change while rednering.

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">SELECT</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">23</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">32</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">44</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">61</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

   <input type="button" id="MyButton"/>
```

Then you can do like this with Jquery Code:

```
$('#MyButton').click(function(){
   $('#DropDownList2').val("3");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

Using the value to select the option:

```
$('some_button_id').click(function() {
    $('select[id*=DropDownList2]').val( 3 ); //To select 44
});
```

**Or using the ClientID of the ASP.NET control:**

```
$('some_button_id').click(function() {
    $('select#<%=DropDownList2.ClientID%>').val( 3 ); //To select 44
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
var dropDownList2ID = "#<%=DropDownList2.ClientID%>";
var buttonID = "#idOfButton";

//...

$(buttonID).click(function() {
    $(dropDownList2ID).val(3);
});
```